# How to use edge match tool for a larger tolerance? It seems that snapping tolerance didn't work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, snapping, spatial-adjustment

When I use edge snapping in spatial adjustment to connect two layers, I find that it works on the lines which are close to each other (about 3 meters). But when the distance became large (about 8 meters), it does not work.

I tried to set the snap tolerance, but it did not work too.
[image]

Comment: are you trying to set Snapping Options to force your edge snap to work?  Or for your mouse to snap to a vertex/edge?

Comment: I tried to use edge snap

Comment: Snapping options won't affect the edge snap.  You need to set your edge snap options on the Spatial Adjustment toolbar

Comment: Im using arcgis 10.3

Comment: Really ?....but i didn't find an option about tolerance or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. To set the tolerance for edge match tool, you have to set the tolerance there "Click the Editor menu, point to Snapping, then click Options."

For more info, http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Setting_the_snapping_tolerance_classic_snapping/001t00000048000000/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the default snapping of 10 pixel and see if that solve the problem. As 100000000 is too big snapping tolerance. Also check if the projection that you are using is correct. Sometime the conflict in projections, especially if you are adding several shapefiles with different projections in the same map view, can cause such an issue.

Comment: sorry, It did not work on 8 meters. And i even have some lines whose distance between each other are beyond 20 meters.

Comment: What projection are you using?

Comment: Gauss, Beijing54 19n